# when using fathpath installer it only enables eth0 while we use eth1

Tags: maas

when we use fasthpath installer in maas
commissioning and enlisting goes without trouble via eth1

eht1 is is connect to our vlan with maas dhcp

but when using fasthpath installer when starting the node maas
it get to the point that it want connect to cloud-init and we see the following

local true 127.0.0.1
eth0 true - -
eth1 false - -

why is eth1 disabled?
because thats why it can't get a ip address to connect to cloud-init

we use maas 1.6.0